# How can solve this mysql unique id providing odd numbers?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I am having trouble in inserting unique id in my table   the unique id display in my mysql is 1,3,5,7...... how can i make my sql into 1,2,3,4,5,6.... etc

here is my table script

```
CREATE TABLE  `comi`.`da_activity_logs123` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `vqid` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `comi_status` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `activity_logs` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date_logs` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: You may find the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html) insightful. The cause is most likely table locking for concurrent inserts, and/or an increment offset.

Comment: FWIW: the auto-increment PK ID *cannot* be relied on to be dense (deleted records or aborted transactions), and should not be used for this (or ordering) purpose. So "don't worry about some gaps", and treat auto-increment IDs as *opaque values* D:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database has most likely been configured for replication.  Which means that when you create a new auto incrementing record it will be incremented by a set value, rather than just increasing by 1 each time.

Under replication each msyql server will have a different `auto_increment_offset` and `auto_increment_increment` value configured to avoid collisions when records are created using `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

You can see the auto increment settings from the mysql client:

`mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';`

`+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| auto_increment_increment | 1     |
| auto_increment_offset    | 1     |
+--------------------------+-------+`

See: [DOC: MySQL Replication Options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-master.html) for more info.